# Weird logo glitching

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

My browser of choice is Firefox (currently 45.0.1) running on Windows 10. When reading the main or meta sites at different zoom levels, some odd things happen to the site logo in the top left.

[image: Logo glitch 1]
[image: Logo glitch 2]
[image: Logo glitch 3]

Is it just me? I haven't noticed any similar issues on other SE boards, or other sites generally.

Comment: 45.0.1 on Win7 is not showing it. I'll give [Pavel](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/589/site-design-for-raspberry-pi-community) a ping but maybe it's just on your side ;)

Comment: i will try to reproduce it and fix it if that issue shows up:) thanks for reporting:)

Comment: Looks like an issue with your graphics card/browser. This kind of tearing is not under SE control (could be an issue with how the browser is rendering SVG).